# Selenium Webdriver: How to click on a hidden element of a specific row from a tablelist (Java)?

Tags: java, wordpress, selenium, html-lists

I am quite new in java and selenium and I hope to be as clear as possible.

**Test Scenario:**
Add a category (ex: TestCategoryName), validate creation of category, delete category, validate deletion of category.

**How it works:** once the category has been created, the created category will appear in an additional row at the end of a table. This table obviously contains all the created categories but each row of that table contains three elements:

1. the name of the created category
2. below the name of the created category, there are two hidden elements: "edit" and "delete" options. These two options are only visible when the user moves the mouse to a specific row containing one category e.g. the "category name".

*PS:* I can't click on the category name or else I would access another page.

**My difficulty:** I need to delete only one category, which is the last one created (e.g. the last row of the table). However, even though the "delete" option (="Löschen") can be "seen", it will not be clicked.
It seems I can only find all the "Löschen" options ("delete" options) of the table but I can't click on that one specific "Löschen" for that specific category "TestCategoryName".

The code itself of the previously described table looks like the following:

```html
<tbody id="the-list" data-wp-lists="list:tag">
  <tr id="tag-1">_</tr
  <tr id="tag-1">_</tr
  <tr id="tag-1">_</tr
  <tr id="tag-1">_</tr
  <tr id="tag-1">_</tr
  <tr id="tag-1">_</tr
  <tr id="tag-1">_</tr
  <tr id="tag-1">
    <th scope="row" class="check-column">_</th>
    <td data-colname="Name" class="name column-name has-row-actions column-primary">
      <strong>
        <a href="#/projects/active?category=172" class="row-title">TestCategoryName</a>
      </strong>
      <div class="row-actions">
       <span class="edit">
         <a href="#">Bearbeiten</a>
         " |

         <a href="#">Löschen</a>
       </span>
      </div>
     </td>
```

- the categories are listed in the table with no real ID, they are recognisable through their category name.
- the options "edit" ("Bearbeiten") and "delete" ("Löschen") are not directly "linked" to the category name.

While debugging, no matter what I code (I tried using size(), equals, loops and other solutions offered in the internet...), my test always throws an exception once it trys to "click" on the "delete" option:

**here is one of the drafts of the method (not working of course) that wants to click the "delete" option of a specific category:**

```
/**
     * Deletes the created category.
     * 
     * @param categoryName
     */
    public void deleteNewCategory(String categoryName) {
        System.out.println("--- Delete Created Category ---");
//      int rowCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath(CATEGORY_LIST_FIELD)).size();
//      int rowNumber = driver.findElements(By.xpath(String.format(CATEGORY_LIST_NAME, categoryName))).size();
        WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format(CATEGORY_LIST_NAME, categoryName)));
        WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(CATEGORY_DELETE_OPTION));
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.moveToElement(element1).moveToElement(element2).pause(1000).click().build().perform();
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
    }
```

**here are the Xpaths (the Xpath for the "delete" option might not be specific enough, maybe a specific //tr is needed):**

```
private static final String CATEGORIES_LIST_CONTAINER = "//tbody[contains(@id, 'the-list')]";
private static final String CATEGORY_LIST_FIELD = CATEGORIES_LIST_CONTAINER + "//tr";
private static final String CATEGORY_LIST_NAME = CATEGORIES_LIST_CONTAINER + "//a[contains(text(), '%s')]";
private static final String CATEGORY_DELETE_OPTION = "//a[@innertext='Löschen']";
```

**here is the invokeMethod from my debugging:**

```
/**
 * @see org.junit.platform.commons.support.ReflectionSupport#invokeMethod(Method, Object, Object...)
 */
public static Object invokeMethod(Method method, Object target, Object... args) {
    Preconditions.notNull(method, "Method must not be null");
    Preconditions.condition((target != null || isStatic(method)),
        () -> String.format("Cannot invoke non-static method [%s] on a null target.", method.toGenericString()));

    try {
        return makeAccessible(method).invoke(target, args);
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        throw ExceptionUtils.throwAsUncheckedException(getUnderlyingCause(t));
    }
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below xpath-

```
//a[text()='TestCategoryName']/parent::*/following-sibling::div/span[@class='edit']//a[text()='Löschen']
```